# Python function unexpectedly returns True when or operator is in use

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I'm a bit of a newbie so this may very well be just a stupid oversight of mine (although, I suppose that would make this issue easier to solve)

When I run the following code:

```
xoro = [0 for i in range(9)]
checkeD = [False for i in range(9)]
potplay = 0

def checkeR(box_x): #This checks if a move has been played in a given box.
    global checkeD
    print(xoro[int(box_x)]) #prints "0", as no augmentations were made to xoro since declaration
    if xoro[int(box_x)] == 1 or 4:
        checkeD[int(box_x)] = True

checkeR(0)
print(checkeD[0])
```

What should happen is when `xoro[0]` is passed through the if statement, since xoro[0] = 0 and does not fit the if statement's requirements, checkeD[0] should remain false, yet when run, the code returns checkeD[0] = True. What's more interesting is that when we remove the `or` operator, making the if statement `if xoro[int(box_x)] == 1:`, the code works as expected, returning False.

I have absolutely no idea what is going on it it would be great if someone helped.

Comment: If you're trying to compare `xoro[int(box_x)]` to both 1 and 4 you should use something like:  `xoro[int(box_x)] == 0 or xoro[int(box_x)] == 4` Because currently your expression is being evaluated as `xoro[int(box_x)] == 1 or bool(4)` and `bool(4)` is always `True`

Comment: As an aside, `global checkeD` is totally pointless and should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly if statements don't work like that. You must compare it to both possibilities.

```
if xoro[int(box_x)] == 1 or xoro[int(box_x)] == 4:
```

But because you are using `or` and not `and` you can use `in`.

```
if xoro[int(box_x)] in [1,4]:
```